# WP7 items to be shown in a loopingselector

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm using a loopingselector to visualize flags, which are loaded in a list in the classic way, as shown:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<DataContinent> data = new List<DataContinent>(); 
    data.Add(new DataContinent() { Flag = new Uri("/Images/Albania.png", UriKind.Relative).ToString() });
    data.Add(new DataContinent() { Flag = new Uri("/Images/Andorra.png", UriKind.Relative).ToString() });
    ...
    ...
    this.loopingSelectorContinent.DataSource = new ListLoopingDataSource<DataContinent>() {Items = data, SelectedItem = data[0]};
}
```

Is it possible to load in the loopingselector, in runtime, different images according to the continent chosen or, as an alternative, prevent the loop of some items?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to solve the problem that I'm going to describe since it could be useful for somebody else.
Basically, instead of initializing the loopingselector inside the Main it can be done outside and after that call the proper function when necessary.
Here an example:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Europe(); //standard visualization
}

public void Europe()
{
    List<DataContinent> data = new List<DataContinent>(); 
    data.Add(new DataContinent() { Flag = new Uri("/Images/Albania.png", UriKind.Relative).ToString() });
    data.Add(new DataContinent() { Flag = new Uri("/Images/Andorra.png", UriKind.Relative).ToString() });
    ...
    ...
    this.loopingSelectorContinent.DataSource = new ListLoopingDataSource<DataContinent>() {Items = data, SelectedItem = data[0]};
}
public void Africa()
{
    List<DataContinent> data = new List<DataContinent>(); 
    data.Add(new DataContinent() { Flag = new Uri("/Images/Algeria.png", UriKind.Relative).ToString() });
    data.Add(new DataContinent() { Flag = new Uri("/Images/Angola.png", UriKind.Relative).ToString() });
    ...
    ...
    this.loopingSelectorContinent.DataSource = new ListLoopingDataSource<DataContinent>() {Items = data, SelectedItem = data[0]};
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //loopingselector populated with European flags
{
Europe();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //loopingselector populated with African flags
{
Africa();
}
```